# how to loop subcategories with their categories?

Tags: php, mysql, html, templates

EDIT: ok let me be a bit more clear i have a html file name file.html it is like this:

{category}
{sybcategory}

and i have a index file which is like this:

class template 
{
    var $page;

```
function add_file($file){
    $this->page = file_get_contents($file);
    return $this->page;
}

function vars($array)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        $this->page = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $this->page);
    }
    echo $this->page;
}
```

}

$template = new template();

$template->add_file('file.html');

$template->file_vars(array('category' => $row_cat['title'], 'subcategory' => $row_subcat['title']));

now, this only outputs the title and the subcategory only once how do i loop that and i have not added the mysql query here because i don't wanna waste your more time please if you know how to do it then let me know.

Comment: Why remove the `while-loops` tag? It's more relevant than the `mysql` one.

Comment: Thanks for the update - that entirely depends on what templating system your using? Smarty by any chance?

Comment: no i made a template engine my self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$cats = array();

while (mysql_fetch_assoc($mycategory))
{    
    $cats[$cat_title] = array();

    while (mysql_fetch_assoc($mysubcategory))
    {
        $cats[$cat_title][]  $subcat_title;
    }
}
```

This will give you an array  of arrays. The first array contains  the category titles as keys and they will contain an array of all the sub category titles.

Comment: Well yes i learn how to accept the answers in the previous question only. anyways i think you are not getting what i am trying to ask let me edit it up and explain correctly.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing everything within those whiles you have there?

```
while (mysql_fetch_assoc($mycategory)){

  $catsArray[] = $cat_title;

  while (mysql_fetch_assoc($mysubcategory)){

   $catsArray[] = $subcat_title;

  } 
}
```

This way you'll have a single array with all the cats followed by their subcats.

Hope it helps a bit :)

EDIT: I think I misunderstood your question, what I answered covers how you can group them, but what you're asking in the end is a template engine such as Smarty, which can't be "summarized" in a single answer here in Stackoverflow, you'd need to build the engine before you can use something like {catArray}.